# How can I get rid of Picturebox' border?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have `PictureBox` and I set its `BorderStyle` to `None` but I'm still getting a border around it. How can I get rid of that?

What more details? My Image doesn't have borders itself.
I use the code

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgOpenFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                img = new Bitmap(dgOpenFile.FileName);

                picture.Size = img.Size;
                picture.Image = img;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

To open and display the image:

Image is 10x10. They are below (at 800%)

original:

http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/2409/originallu.png

and how it is displayed:

http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/7088/displayed.png

Comment: but, I didn't get any border.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details. Setting the BorderStyle to None should not show any border at all.

Comment: are you sure that, getting border in run time. it will show a dotted border when you set BorderStyle to None. but when you run the application it wont...

Comment: I think Your image itself have border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What should be done is:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picture.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work when I set it to `None` from Form Designer. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

Check `Padding` property of your `PictureBox`

Set it `0`

```
pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(0);
```

Comment: `Padding` is already at 0. I just figured out how to solve my problrm but still don't understand why is it happening...

Comment: @Ichibann: Do you get border at design time as well?

Comment: Don't understand your question. I click on my `PictureBox` then find `BorderStyle` in Properties toolbox and set it to `None`.

Comment: @Ichibann:Do you get border around your pictureBox before running your application ?